# Set files timestamp using cmd (.bat - recursive)

Tags: file, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, timestamp

I have code:

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*.*) do (
    pushd
    echo %%~fa
    cd %%~fa
    cd
    popd
    copy /b "*.*" +,,
)
:end
pause
```

What I'm trying to do, is to touch all the files in the current folder (this .bat is already in this folder and doesn't matter) and subfolders with the current timestamp. Script is nearly done, but does not do what I exactly want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /d /r . %%f in (*) do (
    pushd "%%~ff"
    copy /b "*.*" +,,
    popd
)
```